# GVim theme italics cuts off character

Tags: vim, themes

[image]

The italics cause the last character to cut off, making it hard to see.

Is this something that can be fixed without removing the italics style from the theme?

Using GVim with *wombat* theme on Windows.

**EDIT**: thanks kemp, it was indeed a font bug.

Comment: Might be a font bug (that looks like fixedsys on windows), have you tried another font?

Comment: If this question is answered, probably you should close it. That might involve answering by yourself and selecting it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Kemp suggested and Marco acknowledged, it's a font issue.  Here's how to fix it:

```
:set guifont=Consolas
```

Or, in vimrc:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
  set guifont=Menlo
elseif has("gui_running")
  set guifont=Consolas
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

As kemp suggested, the issue was with the font. Switching the font to something other than fixedsys resolved the issue.